# When django project is runing, how to independently run a python command to change data by django ORM?

Tags: django, python-3.x

My django project is running, at same time I want to use `python-fire` moudle in my  `fire_command.py` for updating data manually.

like this: `python fire_command.py ManagementCommand  change_data --date=20190101`

management is one of my apps, structure as below:

```
├── management
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tasks.py
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── fire_command.py
```

#### `fire_command.py`:

```py
import datetime, os, sys

import fire

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(BASE_DIR)
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')

from management.models import ModelOne


class ManagementCommand(object):

    def change_data(self, date):

        model_one_obj = ModelOne.objects.all().first()
        model_one_obj.dt = date
        model_one_obj.save()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fire.Fire()
```

#### My problem

My problem is when I run `python fire_command.py ManagementCommand  change_data --date=20190101` , it raise error  `AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")`

can you help me about it, what should i do to make it correctly running..

great thanks..

Comment: is app containing management commands registered in settings.py

Comment: my bad, missed `django.setup()` in my code ... thanks for your feeding back

Comment: I think you should use django commands: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: You should still write it as a custom management command instead - if only to follow conventions so someone else having to maintain your project can pick up more easily.

Comment: good to know, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its better to use [Django Custom commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-management-commands/). You can try like this:

```
# your_app/management/commands/fire_command.py

from datetime import datetime
from your_app.models import ModelOne
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Change Date'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('change_date', type=str, help='Change Date')

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        change_date = kwargs['change_date']
        model_one_obj = ModelOne.objects.all().first()
        model_one_obj.dt = datetime.strptime(change_date, '%Y%m%d')  # convert it to date
        model_one_obj.save()

# Usage
python manage.py fire_command 20190101
```